# "vstack"ing a 3d Numpy ndarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Let's say I have a 3d NumPy `ndarray` with shape `(n, 0, 2)` and I want consecutively to fill it along the 1st dimension with entries of shape `(1,2)`, using some function like `vstack`.

In other words I want to switch from a `(n, 0, 2)` `ndarray` to a `(n, m, 2)` one. However, since I don't know in advance `m`, I need some dynamical update of my array.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate, please. The first array of size `(n, 0, 2)` has zero elements, and will continue to have so until all dimensions are larger than zero. I don't see how you can achieve that by adding/filling with element of shape `(1, 2)`.

Comment: @HannesOvrén I updated the question, hoping it is clearer now.

Comment: I still don't undestand how you are supposed to go from `(n, 0, 2)` to `(n, 1, 2)` with a `(1, 2)` array as new data. The former has `2n` elements, but the latter has only `2` elements.

Comment: Usually you don't fill an empty array, you already create it filled, performing a single `vstack` operation with all your sub-arrays.

Comment: I would think that you would need the second input to be `(n, 1, 2)` for that. I dont think you can grow on two dimensions with simply a concatenation. So, if `a` is `(n,0,2)` and b is `(n,1,2)`, you can grow along `axis=1` to reach something like `(n, m, 2)`.

Comment: Yeah, I probably missed the correct setting of the problem. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build a 3d array 'dynamically' it is better to collect the subarrays in a list and perform the 'stacking' once at the end

```
In [21]: alist = []
In [22]: for i in range(3):
    alist.append(np.arange(i,i+8).reshape(2,4))
   ....:     
In [23]: alist
Out[23]: 
[array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6, 7]]), array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8]]), array([[2, 3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8, 9]])]
```

Once collected they can be joined in any compatible way.  `np.array` joins them on a new axis at the start.

```
In [24]: np.array(alist)
Out[24]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6, 7]],

       [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8]],

       [[2, 3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8, 9]]])
In [25]: _.shape
Out[25]: (3, 2, 4)
```

`np.stack` can do the same, or can create the new axis else where.

```
In [26]: np.stack(alist,axis=1).shape
Out[26]: (2, 3, 4)
```

`concatenate` and `vstack` join on an existing axis.

```
In [27]: np.concatenate(alist, axis=0).shape
Out[27]: (6, 4)
```

Starting with an array that has a 0 dimension is poor practice.  You don't  `fill it in`.  At best you concatenate it with other 3d arrays.  It's a slow and error prone imitation of appending to `[]` list.